# Log visited URLs via OpenVPN?

Tags: vpn, openvpn

I'm installing an OpenVPN server. Started a container using [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/linuxserver/openvpn-as) and also monitored it using [this](https://hub.docker.com/r/ruimarinho/openvpn-monitor). It shows the active connections, but not the browsed URLs. I would like to know how I can monitor the URLs visited by the employees of the org. Pls note that I just want the URLs, not the payload.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

OpenVPN is not capturing traffic by default. You need a way to sniffing traffic between client and server. There are many tools for doing this like [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/)
wireshark can capture traffic based on defined filter that you specify on it like source, destination , protocol ,time and etc...

Comment: Well, Wireshark needs to be installed on the client machine. Is it possible to do something at the server end itself?

Comment: No it should be installed on the server. When client connect to the vpn server, your server will appear as if it was physically on the same network of the client, so wireshark works on regular network interface to obtain the data that you need.

Comment: Even if I set up wireshark, how would I get to know which user is browsing which url?

Comment: Can you pls have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65122190/modify-request-from-open-vpn-server