# Modify request from Open VPN server

Tags: https, tcplistener, squid, openvpn, mitmproxy

I'm doing a POC on a product where I need to set up a VPN server and manipulate the request (basically the URL parameters, not the headers/form data). I'll share my findings in this post and the blockers too. Need some advice on the blockers.

**My setup:-**

```
oVPN client -> oVPN server -> Squid Proxy -> Internet
                                  |
                               Logstash
                                  |
                                Kibana
```

Logstash parses the squid proxy logs (the browsed URLs) and dumps it to ES which is then viewed on kibana.

**Findings.**

1. When my client connects with the VPN server and browses the **HTTP** URLs (both from app and mobile browser), it shows up on the Kibana. I can manipulate the request too.
2. When my client connects with the VPN server and browses the **HTTPs** URLs (from the mobile
   browser), it shows up on the Kibana. I can manipulate the request too. This is because the browser has a set of authorized public certificates which allows for a successful handshake.
3. When my client connects with the VPN server and browses the **HTTPs** URLs (from the apps), it does not shows up on the Kibana. This is because of **certificate pinning**. The connection is dropped by the client upon not being able to verify the domain certificate. And as a result of which, I cannot manipulate the request.

**Blockers**

What I'm stuck at is pointer 3? I know ISPs and VPNs can track my browsing history, not just domains but the complete URL. I know theoretically, my HTTPs requests are encrypted, and hence only domain names are visible. There's something I'm missing that I'm not aware of. Want some opinion here on how this is possible?

Expecting some positive news.

Comment: I am sorry but after reading your post I am fully sure I understand your question. Yes if the ap performs certificate pinning you can't intercept and modify it. As long as you don't "unpin" the app or the certificate pinning code has a bug there is nothing you can do. And the domain names are only visible unless TLS 1.3 is used.

Comment: How do ISP gets to know about my browsing history?

Comment: Or the other free VPN providers? That make business out of our browsing data?

Comment: Don't forget the DNS traffic. Usually it is totally unprotected and shows the domains you are surfing to.

Comment: DNS traffic? I didn't get it. Is there any way I can look into it? How do VPN companies sniff into my data?